# When I open Terminal on Visual Studio Code I found error "Cannot create process, error code 5" Please help me to solve this issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 5).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to first disable all add on's you have and then restart your visual studio see if it works . If not try upgrading it to more recent version.

> It seems to be a compatibility issue with different versions and addons